# Determining the result of a convolution operation

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

Following guide from https://medium.com/mlreview/a-guide-to-receptive-field-arithmetic-for-convolutional-neural-networks-e0f514068807 I'm attempting to calculate the number of output features using code below :

The output of :

```
%reset -f

import torch
import torch.nn as nn

my_tensor = torch.randn((1, 16, 12, 12), requires_grad=False)
print(my_tensor.shape)

update_1 = nn.Conv2d(16, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
print(update_1(my_tensor).shape)
```

is :

```
torch.Size([1, 16, 12, 12])
torch.Size([1, 16, 6, 6])
```

How is `torch.Size([1, 16, 6, 6])` calculated in the context of applying formula :

[image]

(taken from https://medium.com/mlreview/a-guide-to-receptive-field-arithmetic-for-convolutional-neural-networks-e0f514068807)

Attempting to calculate the number of output features manually by applying the formula :

```
stride = 2
padding = 1
kernel_size = 3

# 2304 as n_in = 1 * 16 * 16 * 12

n_out = ((2304 + (2 * padding) - kernel_size) / stride) + 1

print(n_out)
```

prints : 1152.5

But the produced number of output features is `print(1 * 16 * 6 *6)` = 576. I've taken the product of 1,16,6,6 as this is the shape of the result of `print(update_1(my_tensor).shape)`

Update :

Based on questions below I've updated code to :

```
%reset -f

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from math import floor

stride_value = 2
padding_value = 1
kernel_size_value = 3

number_channels = 3
width = 10
height = 12

my_tensor = torch.randn((1, number_channels, width, height), requires_grad=False)
print(my_tensor.shape)

update_1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=number_channels, 
                     out_channels=16, 
                     kernel_size=kernel_size_value, 
                     stride=stride_value, 
                     padding=padding_value)

print(update_1(my_tensor).shape)

n_out = floor((number_channels + (2 * padding_value) - kernel_size_value) / stride_value) + 1
print(n_out)
```

`print(my_tensor.shape)` produces : 
torch.Size([1, 3, 10, 12])

`print(update_1(my_tensor).shape)` produces : 
torch.Size([1, 16, 5, 6])

`print(update_1(n_out).shape)` produces : 
2

2 does not match the number of output features in each dimension. Have I implemented the calculation correctly ?

As the number of horizontal features produces is 5 and number of vertical features produces is 6 is this formula not applicable where the number of features differ as for an image it does not make sense to have differing x and y axis values length ?

Comment: No, by convention, the 2D convolution is done in the image plane, consuming all the channels given by first Conv2D parameter, and producing the number of channels in the second Conv2D parameter. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see where you confusion is coming from. The formula computes the linear number of outputs, whereas you assume that it operates on the whole tensor.

So the correct code is:

```
from math import floor

stride = 2
padding = 1
kernel_size = 3

n_out = floor((12 + (2 * padding) - kernel_size) / stride) + 1

print(n_out)
```

Therefore, it outputs 6 "horizontal" features.
Since the input tensor has the same "vertical" dimension (12), the formula will also produce 6 "vertical" features.
Finally, 16 is the number of output channels you have specified in Conv2d.

Putting it all together, the output is

```
1 image in a batch,
16 channels,
6 horizontal features, and
6 vertical features,
```

which totals in 576 features.

**UPDATE**

By convention, the number of output channels is **not** calculated by the formula, but provided manually as a second parameter to nn.Conv2d.

Therefore, to correct the second code above:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from math import floor

stride_value = 2
padding_value = 1
kernel_size_value = 3

number_channels = 3
width = 10
height = 12

my_tensor = torch.randn((1, number_channels, width, height), requires_grad=False)
print(my_tensor.shape)

update_1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=number_channels, 
                     out_channels=16, 
                     kernel_size=kernel_size_value, 
                     stride=stride_value, 
                     padding=padding_value)

print(update_1(my_tensor).shape)

n_out1 = floor((width + (2 * padding_value) - kernel_size_value) / stride_value) + 1
n_out2 = floor((height + (2 * padding_value) - kernel_size_value) / stride_value) + 1
print("(Expected: 5, 6)", n_out1, n_out2)
```

Answer (score 0):

That article has a very strange, non-standard way of using the term "features". They are really referring to "pixels" or more generally the size of the feature maps in each dimension.
Restricting outselves to images, the formula then just computes the number of pixels per image dimension. So in this case, we have `n_in = 12` and `n_out = 6` in each dimension (so a 12-pixel-wide input gives a 6-pixel-wide output), and the formula matches.

If we want the actual number of *features* in the output, we would thus get 16*6*6.

Comment: You plugged `number_channels` into the equation. However, as I tried to explain, this formula is for the height/width. If you plug in the width of 10, you get the correct result of 5. If you plug in the height of 12, you get the correct result of 6. This means the "image" that comes out of the convolution is 5 pixels wide and 6 pixels high. It also has 16 channels which is simply the value specified in the convolution.